# PostgreSQL repmgr where to send queries

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, psql

I'm using Postgres 11.5 and docker. I have started 3 containers - 1 master and 2 slaves.

pg-0 master:

```
docker run --detach --name pg-0 \
   --network my-network \
   --env REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES=pg-0,pg-1,pg-2 \
   --env REPMGR_NODE_NAME=pg-0 \
   --env REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME=pg-0 \
   --env REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST=pg-0 \
   --env REPMGR_PASSWORD=repmgrpass \
   --env POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=secretpass \
   bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:latest
```

pg-1 slave:

```
docker run --detach --name pg-1 \
  --network my-network \
  --env REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES=pg-0,pg-1,pg-2 \
  --env REPMGR_NODE_NAME=pg-1 \
  --env REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME=pg-1 \
  --env REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST=pg-0 \
  --env REPMGR_PASSWORD=repmgrpass \
  --env POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=secretpass \
  bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:latest
```

pg-2 slave:

```
docker run --detach --name pg-2 \
  --network my-network \
  --env REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES=pg-0,pg-1,pg-2 \
  --env REPMGR_NODE_NAME=pg-2 \
  --env REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME=pg-2 \
  --env REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST=pg-0 \
  --env REPMGR_PASSWORD=repmgrpass \
  --env POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=secretpass \
  bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:latest
```

Replication works fine between containers, and also if I stop master pg-0 
then pg-1 \ pg-2 takes over to be the master.

My issue is, if I have python application on a different container that connect to db pg-0 master
What do i do when the master is changing to pg-1 or pg-2? I don't want db connection to try to connect to all 3 servers, I'm sure there is a better way.

The way I connect from python app is using the container name - host =pg-0
What do to when db master host name container changed?

**EDIT :**
this what i try in API

```
>>> psycopg2.connect(host="db-0, db-1", user="user", password="password", database="data")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db-0, db-1" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

my package is psycopg2-2.8.4 and using python3.7

Comment: I don't know if Python uses libpq, but libpq supports providing multiple hostnames in the connection string and will then handle the failover. https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/10/23/seamless-application-failover-using-libpq-features-in-postgresql/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name im thinking of using pgbounce i think it will be the best solution, ill post an answer if ill be able to set it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by installing:

```
pip3 install postgres
```

and then command:

```
psycopg2.connect(host="db-0, db-1", user="user", password="password", database="data")
```

Worked fine but didn't really route to the next host if first the host is down.
Here is my workaround:

It queries all db containers in a loop, and if one of db returns in the `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` query `False`, then it means it is the master.

So all my insert/delete/update queries go to this in a function. (`def db_master`), and all other "select" queries go to the same loop in a different function that checks only the connection. (`def db`):

```
import psycopg2

hosts = ["db-0", "db-1"]

for i in hosts:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname='data', user='user', host=i, password='password')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();")
    result = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    if result is False:
        master = i
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname='data', user='user', host=master, password='password')
```

Comment: FYI: The [postgres](https://pypi.org/project/postgres/) module that you installed through PIP is a wrapper around [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/). Unless you're using the *postgres* module elsewhere you only need *psycopg2*.

Comment: @user369450 i have allready installed psycopg2 but it didnt work untill i installed postgres. but now only the string works but it doesnt really do the work if i want it to try each server i have in host= .. so i had to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> What do i do when the master is changing to pg-1 or pg-2?

If your python app is connected to master and master stops you should catch relevant exception and reconnect to the new master. I would suggest to add retries to re-connection attempts as new master election/manual promotion can take time. Of course, some logic should be added for detecting the new master in the app if your goal is to be connected to master only.

> The way i connect from python app is using the container name - host
>   =pg-0 What do to when db master host name container changed ?

The only case of container master hostname change i can think of is master container crash/stop. Then new master container goes up and app may reconnect to it as suggested above.